# Register Value and Memory Address for Read and Write for MAX144 ADC

Tags: stm32, adc

I am using MAX144 ADC and in the Datasheet there is no information given about the control register to read  the ADC values. I am using STM32L452RE micro-controller and using SPI to get data from ADC. Datasheet of the ADC is:

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX144-MAX145.pdf

anyone who encountered the same problem please guide.

my idea is to create a buffer of 2 bytes for SPI RX and store values in it. but i don't know what control register address should be assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion data is not stored internally in a register set.  When you pull CS low the state of SCLK will determine wither it holds the conversion product(after a high to low transition to start it) or start streaming it on the falling edge of the second clock pulse.

This is all noted on page 9 of the data sheet.  Pages 10 & 11 detail how to interface them to standard SPI.

Comment: really thankful to you GB-AE700. 
but for receiving data from slave there must be a buffer in SPI. should i use SPI register of stm32 micro-controller to store and read the data from ADC?

Comment: @NazarHussain Sorry for the late reply.  While there is a small FIFO(32 bits worth, RX & TX), I would just allocate a memory buffer and stream inbound data in to it, either via DMA or one at a time as they come in.